# SQL group by multiple columns but give one range value in clause

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

There is a PostgreSQL statement where multiple fields are selected and should be grouped.

```
select Max(field1),field1,field2,field3,field4,field5,field6,field7,field8,field9,field10, field11
from table2
group by field1,field2,field3,field4,field5,field6,field7,field8,field9,field10, field11
```

Can I group by this query without giving all field names in group by clause? Something like

```
select Max(field1),field1,field2,field3,field4,field5,field6,field7,field8,field9,field10, field11
from table2
group by [2-12]
```

Comment: It's a rare case to have to group by so many columns. And I actually wonder which is easier, simply copy & paste the columns from the select clause or count the number of columns in it and type [2-12] accordingly ;-)

Comment: Those grouped columns which have a functional dependency on one of them do no need to be included in the `group by` clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Postgres allows you to use numbers as column references, but not ranges.  So, you can do:

```
select Max(field1), field1, field2, field3, field4, field5, field6,
       field7, field8, field9,field10, field11
from table2
group by 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12;
```

Comment: Yes it allow numbers. Is there any other database server that allow range in group by?

Comment: No, and numbers aren't ANSI SQL.

Comment: @MuhammadImranTariq . . . Some other databases do (after all, many databases are based on the Postgres code base to some extent).  However, this is not standard SQL.